# how to give a link to execute this

Tags: php, mysql, function

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feedback.subject WHERE branch='cse'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) or die("error : $sql" .mysql_error());
$data =array();
$n=mysql_num_rows($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
$query_result_array[]=$row;
}

    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        {
            $subid=$query_result_array[$i]['subid'];
            $bt =$query_result_array[$i]['batch'];
            $y =$query_result_array[$i]['year'];
            $s = $query_result_array[$i]['semister'];
            $subname=$query_result_array[$i]['subname'];
            $tid = $query_result_array[$i]['tid'];
 $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE teacher.tid='$tid'");
            $row2 =mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
            $tname= $row2['tname'];
echo "<table id='table'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$bt."</td>";
echo "<td>CSE</td>";
echo "<td>".$y."</td>";
echo "<td>".$s."</td>";
echo "<td style='width:150px'>".$subname."</td>";
echo "<td style='width:150px'>".$row2['tname']."</td>";
echo '<form methode="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="report">
      <input type="submit" value="report">
      </form>';
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";


}


function handler($x,$y){
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['SUBID']=$x;
            $_SESSION['TID']=$y;
            echo '<a href="report.php" target="_blank">report</a>';
}
      if(isset($_GET["report'$i'"]))
       {
      handler($query_result_array[$i]['subid'], $query_result_array[$i]['tid']);
      unset ($_GET["report"]);
        }

}





this results a table like
BATCH | BRANCH | YEAR | SEMISTER | SUBJECT NAME | TEACHER NAME |     ACTION    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9      CSE      4       1           DBMS         ABC           REPORT
 9      CSE      4       1           WT           XYZ           REPORT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when i click the report of a row suppose ('ABC' teacher) i want to carry the details ('ABC' and 'DBMS') to further process. but it always carrying the details of last person in the loop(here 'XYZ' and 'WT'). how to get that? is there any alternate process through i can call the handler function for a particular row which carries that particular row details.

Comment: please tell me method without using ajax.. and im new to php so please help me

Comment: I suggest re-read PHP basics. Your code is terribly messy, use of the <form> here does not make any sense. $i has the value of the last pass after the for cycle, so it obviously can't work.

Comment: problem might be understanding the for loop... this is pretty straight forward question and the student deserves an answer on that level.

My answer is below, comment if you need anything specific.

Comment: i donot know any other method to put a link. thats why i used form... ok i l read the basics once. but tel me is there any another way yo give a hyperlink to the php function?

Comment: @Rastko any another way to do it?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover your problems solution. Let me know if you need anything more

Answer (score 0):

just loop through query result array and inside of it place an if which detects when name is what you are looking for, at that moment, fetch current $query_result_array[$i] into a var that you want to carry the data further and break the loop.

If you are fetching by position in the table, you do not even need loop you just go $specific_person_data = $query_result_array[$i]...

So this now contains all of data about the person at position $i in your data table.

Update for links:

Each persons data can be passed to another page through link like this:

linkadress.php**?var1=X&var2=Y&var3=Z...**

and fetched on the other end with $_POST['var1'], $_POST['var2'] etc.

make sure not to echo or return data directly, but on every post var use **strip_tags** for security precaution.

Also here is article of mine on the subject of sensitive data handling and soem basic security:

http://metaphorical-lab.com/blog/?p=443

Comment: i need a hyperlink at each and every row.... on clinking it it goes to the next page by carrying hte details for processing.